# How to return R's NULL in Rcpp code?

Tags: r, null, rcpp

Suppose I have a C++ code to compile with Rcpp and will be called in R.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP to_env(List x) {
  if(x.hasAttribute("names"))
  {
    return x;
  }
  else
  {
    return NULL;
  }
}
```

What should the `NULL` value be to return R's `NULL` instead of a crash?

Comment: You want `R_NilValue`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use this code:

```
return R_NilValue;
```

The same goes for C++ as well as C code; it's part of the R C API.